# How to convert current cygwin directory to windows format

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin

To display current directory I am using `$pwd` which is working fine in Cygwin.

This [document](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-effectively.html) is explaining how to convert cygwin directory to windows format. But why `$cygpath -w pwd` and `$cygpath -w $pwd` is not working?

It is what I am getting in that case:

[image]

Comment: *"Is not working"* is not an error description. Please explain the expected behavior and the observed behavior.

Comment: @IInspectable just updated with details.

Comment: "*explain the expected behavior"* - You skipped that part. Also, don't add a screenshot, when a text representation with identical content can be contrived. Screenshots aren't accessible to text searches.

Comment: try `cygpath -w "\`pwd\`"` or `cygpath -w "$(pwd)"` or `cygpath -w "$PWD"`

Comment: @anishsane all 3 cases are working. Post that as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 11):

try any of these versions:

```
cygpath -w "$(pwd)"
cygpath -w "$PWD"
cygpath -w "`pwd`"
```

Comment: would you please explain why non of these `$cygpath -w pwd` and `$cygpath -w $pwd `was't working however if I run `$pwd` it is displaying current directory

Comment: ^^ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-bash-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command

Comment: `cygpath -w $(pwd)` worked for me, the quoted versions don't.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to remember cygpath - so i created a wrapper around pwd and added to my .bashrc

```
pwd()
{
    if [[ $1 == "-W" ]] ; then 
        cygpath -aw .; 
    else 
        wpwd="-W, --winpath\t  Gives you actual Windoze path"
        err_msg=$(/usr/bin/pwd $* 2>&1);
        let "v = $?"
        if [ $v -eq 1 ] ;  then # have error
            echo "${err_msg}" | sed 's/.*pwd --help.*//' ;
            /usr/bin/pwd --help | sed "s|\(.*  -L, --logi.*\)|  $wpwd\n\1|" 
        else 
            echo "${err_msg}"
        fi
    fi
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

> But why `$cygpath -w pwd` and `$cygpath -w $pwd` is not working?

Git 2.15.x/2.16 (Q1 2018) illustrates that issue, due to UNC paths being also relevant in Cygwin builds and being now tested just like Mingw builds.

See [commit f21d60b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f21d60b4299378f4d99b9d234ae013f81661e838) (31 Oct 2017) by [Adam Dinwoodie (`me-and`)](https://github.com/me-and).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b169d18](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b169d187682ed3f928df7806b00f3a62b83edfef), 09 Nov 2017)</sup>

> ### `t5580`: add Cygwin support
>
> `t5580` tests that specifying Windows UNC paths works with Git.
>   Cygwin supports UNC paths, albeit only using forward slashes, not backslashes,
>   so run the compatible tests on Cygwin as well as MinGW.
>
> **The only complication is Cygwin's `pwd`, which returns a *nix-style
>   path, and that's not suitable for calculating the UNC path to the
>   current directory.
>
>   Instead use Cygwin's `cygpath` utility to get the
>   Windows-style path.**

That is why the test now uses:

```
alias winpwd='cygpath -aw .'
BACKSLASHED="$(winpwd | tr / \\\\)"
```